# Different conjugations of the verb 住む

Tags: grammar

「どちらにお住まいですか。」

「どちらにお住みですか。」

「どちらに住んでいますか。」

Do all of these questions mean "where do you live?" ? 
How are they grammatically different? 
Is 「住まい 」a conjugated form of the verb 「住む 」?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 住まう→お住まいですか
>   住む　→お住みですか

住まう has a meaning like 'to continue living'.
Examples of such expressions include [語]{かた}らう(to continue saying([語]{かた}る)) and [移]{うつ}ろう(to continue changing([移]{うつ}る)).

That is a kind of expressions of a literary style, but お住まいですか is used better than お住みですか
because お住みですか is easily confused with お[済]{す}みですか that has the same pronunciation as it.

Comment: Happy to see you mention the continuative / iterative verb construction (_-a_ verb stem + auxiliary _u_).

Answer (score 2):

There is a good answer in Japanese on [Okwave](http://okwave.jp/qa/q667021.html) for the difference between phrase 1 and 2.

They all mean the "Where do you live?", but the first two are a condensed form of keigo, and the third is in standard polite Japanese.

The first is based on the verb 住まう and the second is based on the verb 住む, which have similar meaning. According to the article I linked, 「どちらにお住まいですか。」is used more often in modern Japanese.